# How do I emit multiple arguments via setup()?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have the following function being passed as an emit to the component:

```
setTray(tray, pk) {
  alert(tray)
  alert(pk)
},
```

Calling inside a component, I am able to reach the function, but not the arguments:

```
setup(props, ctx) {
  ctx.emit('setTray', 'profile-task', pk)
  ctx.emit('setTray', {tray: 'profile-task', pk: pk})
}
```

Both approaches result in the arguments being undefined when `setTray()` is executed. What is the correct syntax in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `emit` function accepts one or two arguments, the event name and the payload  which in your case should be defined as object :

```js
ctx.emit('setTray', {tray: 'profile-task', pk: pk})
```

in parent :

```js
setTray({tray, pk}) {//destruct the payload
  alert(tray)
  alert(pk)
},
```

or in old way :

```js
setTray(payload) {
  alert(payload.tray)
  alert(payload.pk)
},
```